# MVC Query expressions over source type 'dynamic' or with a join sequence of type 'dynamic' are not allowed

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to get this expression working in my Razor file:

```
<span>@($" ({string.Join(", ", from o in comment.CommentStaff.StaffOffices select o.Office.OfficeOrganizationCd)})")</span>
```

But it says "Query expressions over source type 'dynamic' or with a join sequence of type 'dynamic' are not allowed" in the red squiggly in the Razor and the Developer exception page.

Here is my model (@model CommentVM) coming down to the Razor from the controller action:

```
public class CommentVM
{
    public int AuditId { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Controller Action (actually this is coming from the Invoke method in a component. But this shouldn't really make a difference).

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke(int auditId)
    {
        IQueryable<Comment> comments = _commentRepo.Comments.Include(c => c.CommentStaff).ThenInclude(c => c.StaffOffices)
            .Where(c => c.CommentAuditId == auditId)
            .OrderByDescending(c => c.CommentDate).Take(3);

        CommentVM commentVM = new CommentVM
        {
            AuditId = auditId,
            Comments = comments
        };

        return View(commentVM);
    }
```

The Comments Repo returns an IQueryable of Comment objects.

The Comment POCO looks like this:

```
[Table("comment")]
public class Comment
{
    [Key]
    [Column("comment_id")]
    public int CommentId { get; set; }

    [Column("comment_type_cd")]
    public string CommentTypeCd { get; set; }

    [Column("comment_audit_id")]
    public int? CommentAuditId { get; set; }

    [Column("comment_finding_id")]
    public int? CommentFindingId { get; set; }

    [Column("comment_recommend_id")]
    public int? CommentRecommendId { get; set; }

    [Column("comment_action_item_id")]
    public int? CommentActionItemId { get; set; }

    [Column("comment_acd_id")]
    public int? CommentAcdId { get; set; }

    [Column("comment_pdl_id")]
    public int? CommentPdlId { get; set; }

    [Column("comment_cost_nm")]
    public string CommentCostNm { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("comment_tx")]
    public string CommentText { get; set; }

    [Column("comment_dt")]
    public DateTime CommentDate { get; set; }

    #region Navigation Properties
    [Column("comment_staff_id")]
    public short CommentStaffId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CommentStaffId")]
    public Staff CommentStaff { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

So CommentStaff is a navigation property to a Staff object which has a bridge table POCO called StaffOffices for a many to many relationship between Staff and Office.

Here is the bridge table POCO:

```
[Table("staff_office")]
public class StaffOffice
{
    [Column("staff_office_staff_id")]
    public short ID { get; set; }
    public Staff Staff { get; set; }

    [Column("staff_office_office_id")]
    public short OfficeID { get; set; }
    public Office Office { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to get this:

```
<span>@($" ({string.Join(", ", from o in comment.CommentStaff.StaffOffices select o.Office.OfficeOrganizationCd)})")</span>
```

or this:

```
@{ 
                                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                                    foreach(var o in comment.CommentStaff.StaffOffices)
                                    {

sb.Append(o.Office.OfficeOrganizationCd);
                                    }
                                }
                                <span>@sb.ToString()</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a partial view.  I needed to include the model definition of the parent Razor file:

@model CommentVM